# Google Sign in failure in playstore build

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've created a release build which is working fine i.e. I'm able to login using Google sign in. I've uploaded the same build to playstore and now the sign in won't work.

I have also cross checked SHA-1 many times and it is of my keystore i.e. release one.

I'm able to receive fcm but not able to sign in.

Comment: Do you get any error after or while APK uploading to playstore?

Comment: No upload was successful.

Comment: what you mean not able to sign in,?

Comment: Google Sign In basically Google Auth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Few months ago Google changed behaviour of signing apps. After you upload APK Google signs it with another key. You must download this key from Google Play Console and add it's SHA too. Check this for more information

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I Have solved the issue by using simple method 
put blue highlighted sha1 certificate fingerprint string  (that is marked in the picture ) into firebase console too, as like

[image]

put that SHA1 key to firebase console under project setting.

Go to -> https://console.firebase.google.com  select project -> click setting button icon -> choose project setting -> scroll to down -> click  ADD FINGERPRINT button  put SHA1 Key here -> and Save

[image]