# How to solve Google authentication problem in Android app?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-play, google-authentication

I implemented Google authentication in my android app. I use Firebase for server and function. The problem is when I run app from Android Studio, Google authentication works well. But when I upload it to play store, Google authentication fail. It shows 'Authentication failed'.
Stuck here. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you uploading an APK or an AAB?  Do you have the right keyhash stored within Google Play?

Comment: You have to add the release sha1 key to firebase manually. Only the debug sha1 key is added automatically, when you add the app to firebase. Just google how to get the release sha1 key.

Comment: It's most likely because of **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406)**.

Answer (score 1):

Go to

1. Google play console
2. Select you app
3. Select version management from menu
4. Application signing
5. Copy this SHA-1 Certificate Fingerprint key
6. Add this key to your firebase console app.

This will solve your problem.
you can also refer this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954300/google-sign-in-failure-in-playstore-build).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have not added signed key in your firebase project. Go into your project settings and in the bottom, there would be option to add SHA-1 or SHA-25 key of your application. In Google Play Console, You may also find your keys or you may also view your SHA-1 or SHA-25 keys using `keytool`

Answer (score 0):

so the thing is when you upload your app on play store you will get an SHA-1 key from the play store console.

In your play store image description here console go to App signing and get the SHA1 key. Paste this key in your firebase console.

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHJCj.png)